# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tokenize'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use XLNET through transformers. however i keep getting the issue "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tokenize'". I am unsure of how to proceed. if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

```
tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', do_lower_case=True)

print(' Original: ', X_train[1])

# Print the tweet split into tokens.
print('Tokenized: ', tokenizer.tokenize(X_train[1]))

# Print the tweet mapped to token ids.
print('Token IDs: ', tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenizer.tokenize(X_train[1])))




Original:  hey angel duh sexy really thanks haha
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-2b1b432b3e15> in <module>()
      2 
      3 # Print the tweet split into tokens.
----> 4 print('Tokenized: ', tokenizer.tokenize(X_train[2]))
      5 
      6 # Print the tweet mapped to token ids.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

Comment: What is tokenizer? Seems that is nothing on your code

Comment: use `print(tokenizer)` to see whether it is None or not

Comment: Your X_train[2] returns None. "tokenize" cannot process NoneType values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that:

```py
from transformers import XLNetTokenizerFast
tokenizer = XLNetTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', do_lower_case=True)
```

works?
In this case, you are just missing the [sentencepiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) package:

```py
pip install sentencepiece
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In case SenencePience is installed and still have the error

Absolutely, [@cronoik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664872/cronoik) 's answer is the correct one. No doubt regarding it. But if you have installed the [SenencePience](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) package and still have the error, just **`restart the runtime environment and it will work`**.